# How to change Policy Scan type using nessus API?

Tags: api, nessus

I am following documentation present at https://localhost:8834/api/# fro nessus. I listed policies and created new scan with template uuid as "Host Discovery" uuid fetched from the policies list. Problem is it creates new scan with discovery scan type custom. I am not able to figure out how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the available policies and write down the policy id. When you start the scan you should apply that policy id to scan. Unfortunately, this question is old and Nessus has removed API starting version 7.0. I hope you got your answer already !